# How to get the correct full file path from a remote linux machine correct

Tags: c++, linux, path, remote-access, vnc

I use TigerVNC to access a remote linux machine. 
In my current path, if I type "pwd", then I got these lines shown in the ternial:

```
% pwd
/stateflow/devel
[myusername@sb33glnxa64: /stateflow/devel]
%
```

Right now, I want to write a program to run on the remote linux machine under /stateflow/devel/xx directory to save the file under this directory, but I tried to set the `filePath` to either

```
"//sb33glnxa64/stateflow/devel/MyLog.txt"
or
"/stateflow/devel/MyLog.txt"
```

For example:

```
std::ofstream m_fStream;
std::string filePath("//sb33glnxa64/stateflow/devel/MyLog.txt");
m_fStream.open(filePath.c_str(), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
m_fStream << "sMode is " << sMode << std::endl;
m_fStream.close();
```

But neither of them works, I cannot see the MyLog.txt file got created under the /stateflow/devel  directory.

Not sure which path I should use here to set the `filePath` ? Thanks

Note: the program to run is under a unknown temporary path /stateflow/devel/xx . So that's why I need to know the absolute path thus later I can find and open the MyLog.txt.

Comment: Why do you use backslashes? On Linux you use forward slashes like that printed by pwd

Comment: @lan4264 Thank you, I thought \\ is equal to /  on linux. I just tried forward slashes, still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to create the file on a remote Linux system? Is that why you tried adding the hostname in the path?

Comment: @lan4264 Exactly, I tried to add the hostname,  but still doesn't work

Comment: I suspect you are going to need to use some library that implements a remote protocol like `libssh`. (or mount some remote filesystem external to your program)

Comment: Well that is a whole lot harder. As far as I know there is no automatic exporting of file systems. You need to have set up the something like NFS or SAMBA to do this. I have no idea how easy or tricky that is...

Comment: This may be of use: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62677/best-way-to-mount-remote-folder

Comment: @lan4264@Galik  Sorry I forget to mention: the program also run on the remote linux machine under an sub folder of /stateflow/devel  . But the subfolder is created during the run and I do not know the name and the exact path of the sub folder. So that's why I need to know the absolute path thus later I can find and open the MyLog.txt.